# Delimiter in array lists is not working properly

Tags: java, arraylist

Here is my code:

```
while(instructorInput.hasNextLine()) {
     Scanner lineSeperator = new Scanner(instructorInput.next());
     lineSeperator.useDelimiter(",");
     lines.add(lineSeperator.next());
}

System.out.print(lines.get(0) + " ");
System.out.println(lines.get(1));
```

This code outputs:

```
5005 Lizards
```

The code should output:

```
5005 Black Lizards
```

I have tried using:

```
lines.add(lineSeperator.nextLine());
```

But that does not work either.

I am trying to read from a file where the lines look like:

5005,Black Lizards,USA

Comment: you should add the format of the input you are reading, or an example of that input

Comment: Here is the format: 5005,Black Lizards,USA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lines.add(lineSeperator.next());` will add only first value

You need iterarate lineSeprator after using delimiter

```
while(instructorInput.hasNextLine()) {
     Scanner lineSeperator = new Scanner(instructorInput.next());
     lineSeperator.useDelimiter(",");
     while(lineSeperator.hasNext())//use another while to iterate
        lines.add(lineSeperator.next());
}
```

this is what i have tried

```
public class Test{
public static void main(String args[]) {
      Scanner lineSeperator = new Scanner("5005,Black Lizards,USA");
         lineSeperator.useDelimiter(",");
         while(lineSeperator.hasNext())
         System.out.println(lineSeperator.next());

  }
}
```

OUTPUT

```
5005
Black Lizards
USA
```

Comment: @hockey34 i have added code snippet that i run and output